# AWS CDK giving: Could Not determine ordering between: <Stack-Name> after doing a build

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I'm trying to deploy cdk resources of a service

This is my app.ts
I have defined all the required resources and also defined the dependencies but when I build it I ger Coudl not determine ordering between: 
I'm not able to figure out what is going wrong?

```
import {
    Vpc
} from "./igvs/stack/vpc";
import {
    EcsClusterStack
} from "./igvs/stack/ecs_cluster";
import {
    EcsServiceStack
} from "./igvs/stack/ecs_service";
import {
    IGVSPipelineStage,
    Stage
} from './pipeline/igvs_pipeline_properties';
import core = require('monocdk');

const stackName = 'STACK'

const app = new core.App();
const personalBootstrap = BootstrapStack.personalBootstrap(app, {
    account: '',
    region: 'eu-west-1',
    disambiguator: '', 
    stackName: stackName
});

const personalVpc = new Vpc(app, 'user-IGVS-VPC', {
    env: personalBootstrap.deploymentEnvironment,
    stackName: stackName,
    region: personalBootstrap.region,
    stage: Stage.Beta
});

const personalCluster = new EcsClusterStack(app, 'user-IGVS-Cluster', {
    env: personalBootstrap.deploymentEnvironment,
    vpc: personalVpc.vpc,
    stackName: stackName
});

const personalEcsService = new EcsServiceStack(app, 'user-IGVS-StackEcsService', {
    ecsCluster: personalCluster.cluster,
    vpc: personalVpc.vpc,
    stage: Stage.Beta,
    env: personalBootstrap.deploymentEnvironment,
    region: personalBootstrap.region,
    appName: "IGVS-STACK",
    stackName: stackName,
    domainName: ',
    pipelineStage: IGVSPipelineStage.Alpha
});

personalCluster.node.addDependency(personalVpc);

personalEcsService.node.addDependency(personalCluster);
```

But after build I get this error

```
/local/home/user/workspace/IGVS-ExponentialPollingTime/src/SERVICECDK/node_modules/monocdk/lib/cx-api/lib/toposort.js:29
            throw new Error(`Could not determine ordering between: ${Array.from(remaining.keys()).join(', ')}`);
            ^
Error: Could not determine ordering between: IGVS-STACK
    at Object.topologicalSort (/local/home/user/workspace/IGVS-ExponentialPollingTime/src/SERVICECDK/node_modules/monocdk/lib/cx-api/lib/toposort.js:29:19)
    at CloudAssembly.renderArtifacts (/local/home/suslah/workspace/IGVS-ExponentialPollingTime/src/SERVICECDK/node_modules/monocdk/lib/cx-api/lib/cloud-assembly.js:17
8:27)
    at new CloudAssembly (/local/home/user/workspace/IGVS-ExponentialPollingTime/src/SERVICECDK/node_modules/monocdk/lib/cx-api/lib/cloud-assembly.js:35:31)
    at CloudAssemblyBuilder.buildAssembly (/local/home/user/workspace/IGVS-ExponentialPollingTime/src/SERVICECDK/node_modules/monocdk/lib/cx-api/lib/cloud-assembly.
js:255:16)
    at Object.synthesize (/local/home/user/workspace/IGVS-ExponentialPollingTime/src/SERVICECDK/node_modules/monocdk/lib/core/lib/private/synthesis.js:34:20)
    at App.synth (/local/home/user/workspace/IGVS-ExponentialPollingTime/src/InvestigatorGuidedValidatorServiceCDK/node_modules/monocdk/lib/core/lib/stage.js:100:41)
    at process.<anonymous> (/local/home/user/workspace/IGVS-ExponentialPollingTime/src/SERVICECDK/node_modules/monocdk/lib/core/lib/app.js:50:51)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:421:26)
    at process.emit (events.js:314:20)
Subprocess exited with error 1
 ›   Error: Failed to run application build system.

                        BUILD FAILED
```

I'm not able to understand why is this happening I tried this without using addDependency but still faced the same issue Help is really appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Can you provide the code in your `EcsServiceStack`? I'm also confused why you're passing around `stackName` everywhere. Are these bonafide stacks or something else? also did you change the value of `stackName` in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue

I named every stacks stackName a unique one

for VPC : user-VPC-stack, etc and the build was successful